# SQL INSERT missing rows from Table A to Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to insert rows into table 'Data' if they don't already exist.

For each row in Export$, I need the code to check 'Data' for rows that match both Period (date) and an ID (int) - if the rows don't already exist then they should be created.

I'm pretty sure my 'NOT EXISTS' part is wrong - what's the best way to do this?  Thanks for all your help

```
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Data, Export$ WHERE Data.ID = Export$.ID AND Data.Period = Export$.Period)
    INSERT INTO Data (Period, Performance, ID)
    SELECT Period, [Return], [ID] FROM Export$
```

Comment: At first glance your not exists part look ok.  What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: What's wrong is that this will prevent inserting any rows if any (possibly other) rows match (there could be many that are fine to import).

Comment: Oh! Are you trying to insert "missing records" *from* `Export$`? If so, look up `MERGE`. Also, the `,` between Data and Exports there is a CROSS JOIN - I recommend against such syntax.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this:

```
INSERT INTO Data (Period, Performance, ID)
SELECT Period, [Return], [ID] 
FROM Export$ e
where not exists (
select *
from Data
where  ID = e.ID and Period = e.Period)
```

Comment: Although this might work, if you have tons of data your query will take forever. The joins would be a good way to go. You can avoid the inner join as it also may suffer the same performance issue and use Left or right join (depending on your arrangement) and add a where condition to exclude the joining param with null

Answer (score 14):

try something like, will need tweaking to fit your tables

```
insert into data
select * from export
left join data on data.id = export.id
                     and data.period = export.period
where data.id is null
```