# Insert with Left Join and multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join, not-exists

I have the following problem, i have 2 tables:

Table A (with the columns "ColumnA" and "ColumnB")

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 555 |
| 111 | 333 |
| 111 | 444 |
| 222 | 555 |
| 222 | 666 |

Table B (with the columns "ColumnC" and "ColumnD")

| ColumnC | ColumnD |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 222 |
| 111 | 333 |
| 111 | 444 |
| 222 | 444 |

i want to insert the values of table B into table A, as long as a combination of both values is not yet in table A (by joining ColumnA/ColumnC and ColumnB/ColumnD). I know how to work with a left join (and the where column... is null) to add values for one column that is not yet available but i don't know how to do it with two columns (as a combination of two columns).

In other words in my case only these two would be added because the combination of those two is not yet available in table A (i hope it's clear what i mean):

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 222 |
| 222 | 444 |

Tried it with a left join and where column is null clause but couldn't make it work for two columns.

This is what i have so far:

```
select *  from TableA 
left  join TableB on TableA.ColumnB = TableB.ColumnD
and TableB.ColumnA = TableA.ColumnC
where ...
```

Comment: T-SQL is a SQL dialect that is used by multiple products including Sybase, SQL Server, and Azure Synapse. What is the (R)DBMS product you are using here? [Edit] your question to tag that product, and (if relevant) the version tag for the product as well.

Comment: Please add your query to the question. It may be easy to fix. You might want to look at [`exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), e.g. `insert ... where not exists ( ... );`.

Comment: Done, I've tagged my question and added the query i have so far

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL INSERT missing rows from Table A to Table B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843944/sql-insert-missing-rows-from-table-a-to-table-b) Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68705520/insert-only-missing-records-from-a-temporary-table

Comment: try to use Merge.

Comment: How about insert into tableA select * from (select * from tableB except select * from tableA) A?

Comment: <Yoda> Ah, backwards it is. Your join on `left` leaves what is to `TableA` unique. Tables swapped you want or join on `right`. <\Yoda> I thought you wanted the more interesting case of where the pairs matched, but the two values in the row might be swapped, i.e. `ColumnA` to `ColumnD` and `ColumnB` to `ColumnC`. That's not the case. And `TableB.ColumnA = TableA.ColumnC` has the columns or tables swapped since they don't match your sample data.